# Putting KTable data into an external DB

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am having a scenario where I need to put data in a KTable and store that data from KTable into Oracle 11g DB. What is the possible way to do it?

Comment: All you want is to put the data into `KTable`? Without any transformations etc.?

Comment: Have a look into Kafka Connect and the corresponding connectors: https://www.confluent.io/product/connectors/

Comment: @Arek yes I have  to perform transformation, like put only those data which have some matching table name.

Comment: Kafka Connect also support "single message transform" for simple transformation -- so if your transformation are simple enough, you would not need Kafka Streams.

Answer (score 2):

Writing to the DB from Kafka Streams is treated as a side effect, and as such you will be on your own with DB transactions etc. What I would suggest is to do the filtering in a Kafka Streams app and then push the data back to Kafka to another topic. Then, as @Matthias J. Sax suggested you can utilize Kafka Connect to consume that topic and write your data to RDBMS.

Comment: Kafka Connect also support "single message transform" for simple transformation -- so if your transformation are simple enough, you would not need Kafka Streams.